# Загрузка нескольких фотографий сразу

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть функция создания объявления, с возможностью загружать одну фотографию. Не могу переделать таким образом, чтобы можно было загружать и хранить несколько фотографий сразу.

```
<?php 

ULogin(1);

if ($_SESSION['USER_GROUP'] == 2) $Active = 1;
else $Active = 0;

if ($_POST['enter'] and $_POST['text'] and $_POST['price'] 
    and $_POST['email'] and $_POST['phone'] and $_POST['name'] 
    and $_POST['cat']) {

    if ($_FILES['img']['type'] != 'image/jpeg') { 
        if ($_FILES['img']['type'] != 'image/gif') { 
            if ($_FILES['img']['type'] != 'image/png') {
               MessageSend(2, 'Не верный тип изображения.');
            }
        }
    }

    $_POST['name']  = FormChars($_POST['name']);
    $_POST['email'] = FormChars($_POST['email']);
    $_POST['phone'] = FormChars($_POST['phone']);
    $_POST['text']  = FormChars($_POST['text']);
    $_POST['price'] = FormChars($_POST['price']);
    $_POST['link']  = FormChars($_POST['link']);
    $_POST['cat']  += 0;

    if (!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] and !$_POST['link'])
        MessageSend(2, 'Необходимо выбрать файл или указать ссылку.');



    if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
        if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'application/octet-stream')    
            MessageSend(2, 'Не верный тип файла.');

        $_POST['link'] = 0;
    }
    else $num_file = 0;

    $MaxId = mysqli_fetch_row(
                mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT max(`id`) FROM `proporsals`')
            );
    if ($MaxId[0] == 0)
        mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'ALTER TABLE `proporsals` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');
    $MaxId[0] += 1;

    foreach(glob('catalog/img/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $num => $Dir) {
        $num_img ++;
        $Count = sizeof(glob($Dir.'/*.*'));
        if ($Count < 250) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $Dir.'/'.$MaxId[0].'.jpg');
            break;
        }
    }

    MiniIMG('catalog/img/'.$num_img.'/'.$MaxId[0].'.jpg', 'catalog/mini/'.$num_img.'/'.$MaxId[0].'.jpg', 320, 320);


    if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
        foreach(glob('catalog/file/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $num => $Dir) {
            $num_file ++;
            $Count = sizeof(glob($Dir.'/*.*'));
            if ($Count < 250) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $Dir.'/'.$MaxId[0].'.zip');
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `proporsals`  VALUES ($MaxId[0], '$_POST[name]', $_POST[cat], '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[text]', '$_POST[price]', NOW(), $Active , $num_file, $num_img, '$_POST[link]', 0, '')");

    MessageSend(2, 'Предложение добавлено', '/proporsals');
}
?>
```

Comment: Оформите код так, чтобы он был читабельным. Это - первый шаг к решению любой проблемы.

Comment: прежде чем переделывать это для нескольких фото, лучше бы упростили то что есть.

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода, как сделать мультизагрузку изображений через один Browse File

**HTML**

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 // Count total files
 $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

 // Looping all files
 for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
   $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

   // Upload file
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);

 }
} 
?>
```

Далее, обрабатывайте массив изображений как Вам угодно.

Но, чтобы сделать нормальный мультиаплоад файлов, нужно:

**1** - Обработка событий jquery/ajax

**2** - PHP - обработка загруженного изображения, а именно, формат файла, размер файла, обрезка (уменьшение фото) до веб формата и допустимого размера. И самое главное, это **обработка изображений на стороне клиента** перед их загрузкой !

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы можно было загружать несколько фотографий сразу надо сделать несколько полей file. Чтобы было удобнее их обрабатывать можно имя поля сделать img[] - тогда данные по этим полям соберутся в массив. Попробуйте

```
<pre><code>
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
</code></pre>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="img[]"><br/>
<input type="file" name="img[]"><br/>
<input type="file" name="img[]"><br/>
<input type="file" name="img[]"><br/>
<input type="file" name="img[]"><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

подать такую форму с несколькими файлами и посмотрите что получится.

Comment: Зачем, если можно на php обработать один массив?